# Django: How to change field name in nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently, I have this serializer:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Token model
    """
    user = UserDataSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
    "key": "d1de7dd82f2b987a6d9f35f1d033876e164f7132",
    "user": {
        "username": "peter258",
        "first_name": "Peter",
        "last_name": "Jones",
        "email": "peter.jones@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

I would like to change the response so instead of saying "user" it says "data" but when I change the serializer to something like this, I only get the "key" in the response:

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Token model
    """
    data = UserDataSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'data')
```

How do you properly change the name of the "user" field inside nested serializers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by providing a `source` argument to your `UserDataSerializer`, which expects the name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field.

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Token model
    """
    data = UserDataSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source="user")

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'data')
```